# PyCharm say "Property can not be read" on valid code

Tags: python, pycharm, typing

Let's look at the following code:

```
import typing

def make_getter(field: str) -> typing.Callable[['A'], int]:
    def getter(self: 'A') -> int:
        return int(self.dict[field])
    return getter

def make_setter(field: str) -> typing.Callable[['A', int], None]:
    def setter(self: 'A', value: int):
        self.dict[field] = str(value)
    return setter

class A:
    def __init__(self, d: dict):
        super().__init__()
        self.dict = d

    get_x = make_getter('foo')
    set_x = make_setter('foo')
    x = property(get_x, set_x)

    def get_y(self) -> int:
        return int(self.dict['bar'])
    def set_y(self, value: int):
        self.dict['bar'] = str(value)
    y = property(get_y, set_y)
```

I defined 2 properties: `x` and `y`. Both should work fine w/o any problems, both should have the same behaivor.
Next, following code:

```
a = A(dict())
a.x = 10
print(a.x)
a.y = 20
print(a.y)
```

PyCharm editor it says: **"Property can not be read"** on `a.x`.
But this code executed well w/o any problems.

The first thought was PyCharm incorrectly inferring types. [But look at this short video I recorded.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzlRPYCBlWY) I can't see any problems with types.

Also:

```
print(repr(a.get_x), repr(a.get_y))
print(repr(A.get_x), repr(A.get_y))
print(repr(A.x), repr(A.y))
```

It's output:

```
<bound method make_getter.<locals>.getter of <__main__.A object at 0x7f7d25145f28>> <bound method A.get_y of <__main__.A object at 0x7f7d25145f28>>
<function make_getter.<locals>.getter at 0x7f7d25132e18> <function A.get_y at 0x7f7d25132f28>
<property object at 0x7f7d25143c78> <property object at 0x7f7d25143cc8>
```

... so `x` and `y` almost equivalent.

**Why PyCharm says that?** I did something wrong or it's kind of bug? How to fix it (w/o disabling this type of warning)?

Answer (score 2):

Setting it to 
`__init__(self, d: dict) -> None` seems to work now.

Comment: Not for me... Still an issue in 2023

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why PyCharm requires this, but explicitly giving the return type of `__init__` made the warnings go away:

`def __init__(self, d: dict) -> object:`

Comment: That works, but **why**? Strange. This makes another warning because `__init__` should not return anything. Technically it should be `-> None` (which is not solves problem). Maybe type-checker stops after seeing this warning and not checks properties anymore?

Comment: I agree it's odd. The only reason I even happened upon it was because it was one of the suggested fixes PyCharm listed.

Comment: @jknupp For me it does not help. Besides that, two more errors appear: ``Expected to return 'object', got no return`` and also ``__init__ should return None``. Where did you find the "suggested fixes"?

Answer (score 0):

Just run into the same issue. What is interesting, this will work properly:

```py
class InlineProperties:
  value = 5

  a = property(lambda self: self.value)


print(InlineProperties().a)
# prints out 5
```

Somehow, this is the only way PyCharm knows that this method with self argument is a proper function that will be a property. No idea why. Also, that works only for getters.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar warning in Pycharm, what I did was add a type hint for the return value of the getter method and it stopped providing the warning.

This sort of code resulted in a warning when using `Example().my_property`

```
class Example(object):

    def get_my_property(self):
        return self.something and self.something.something_else

    my_property = property(get_my_property)
```

This sort of code does not result in the warning for me

```
class Example(object):

    def get_my_property(self) -> bool:
        return self.something and self.something.something_else

    my_property = property(get_my_property)
```